# Class aggregation with object or with object pointer in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose class `ABC` and class `DEF` has Aggregation relationship, and then we can define class `ABC` in the following two ways:

Solution 1

```
class ABC
{
  public:

    ABC() {};
    ~ABC() {};

    DEF defObj;
};
```

Solution 2

```
 class DEF;
 class ABC
{
  public:

    ABC();  
    ~ABC(); 

    std::unique_ptr<DEF> pdefObj;
};

ABC::ABC()
{
  pdefObj = new DEF();
}
ABC::~ABC()
{
}
```

Then my question is in which condition Solution 1 is better than Solution 2. I understand that Solution 2 has advantage when it comes to compilations.

Comment: You won't be able to copy the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just consider Solution 1 the default choice, i.e. use a data member which is an instance of `DEF`, instead of a `unique_ptr<DEF>`.

First, code of solution #1 is the simplest. It is also more efficient, since you don't have a useless heap allocation (required by `unique_ptr`). An heap allocation means going down to the memory manager, and this is an unnecessary cost in this case.

Moreover, if your data member is a pointer, you have worse locality (i.e. less cache-friendly memory layout, and worse performance).

Just consider solution #1, unless you ave some very good reason for #2.
(An example with a *private* data member that uses a `unique_ptr<SomePrivateState>` is the PIMPL idiom, but it seems not your case, since you are exposing `DEF` as a *public* element of your class.)